# Getting a blocked empty window by opening a firefox by FirefoxDriver with OpenQA.Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I'm trying to create a simple Firefox test by using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox in C#.

By running this simple code I'm getting an exception:

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://youtube.com/");
```

The 'GoToUrl' throw this exception:
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException: 'Browsing context has been discarded'

The exception occurs because the firefox window that was opened looks like it is empty as shown in the picture:

[image: Blanked firefox window]

If I'm running the same code that the visual studio executes but manually it succeeds:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "--marionette" "--webdriver-port=2828" "--profile=C:\\Users\\pusersh\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\eb0qdtk8.default-release-1677676201459" "-no-remote"
```

by running this command directly in a cmd it works and firefox shows its content.
It is also running successfully with chrome and edge. It failed only with FirefoxDriver.

I tried to reinstall firefox, match versions, change profilers, and a lot more but it still failed and an exception is thrown.
I'm using Selenium.WebDriver version 4.8.1 and Firefox 110.0.1.

it succeed in python by writing:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://youtube.come")
```

In c# the code is:

```
string geckoDriverLocationDir = @"C:\dev\geckDriverDir\";
string firefoxFullLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(geckoDriverLocationDir);
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = firefoxFullLocation;
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service,options,time);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://youtube.com/");
```

The console output is:

```
1678179247798   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:56909
1678179249937   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "--marionette" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\pusersh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile3nLjzj"
Read port: 56921
```

and get the exception:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException: 'Browsing context has been
> discarded'

What could be the cause and what can solve it?

Comment: This works for me`<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver" Version="0.32.2" />`

Comment: Also, reproduce with GeckoDriver 0.32.2

Comment: Can you try specifying the path to the firefox.exe binary when initializing the driver?

Comment: By default, `new FirefoxDriver()` searches your Windows `%PATH%` for the driver executable. Try specifying the path to the web driver as well as the browser. Or make sure that the Firefox Selenium driver exists in your `%PTH%`. Run `where geckodriver.exe` from a regular Windows command prompt. It should find the EXE file. If not, that is your problem.

Comment: Firefox does open but with blanked content and not responding (for example, If I write URL it does not respond). 
In the same machine it's succeeded with python:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://youtube.come")
but failed with c#.

Comment: I added the code. My C# code gets immediately a 'NoSuchWindowException' after the firefox window opens... the gecodriver.exe exists and the path is correct

Comment: Same code succeed on visual studio 2022 and keep getting same exception on visual studio 2019. Same on other machines in my teammates. What could cause this?

Comment: Which version of Firefox is installed when launching the window fails?